# Linker Error; Cannot Link: _D16TypeInfo_HAyayAa6__initZ

Tags: linker, d

When linking my code, I get the following error:

> ../Build/main.o:(.data._D16TypeInfo_yHAyaAa6__initZ+0x10): undefined reference to `_D16TypeInfo_HAyayAa6__initZ'

I have no idea where the error is occurring, so there is not much code wise I can offer you. There is **a lot** of code.

Comment: What is the compiler, what is the environment?

Comment: @DejanLekic Linux 64 bit

Comment: _D16TypeInfo_HAyayAa6__initZ can't be demangled so without code it is nearly impossible to guess what is going on. Paste it on DPaste, and give us the link...

Comment: I don't know why it didn't demangle automatically, but I think that's immutable(char[])[string]

Comment: If anyone needs to know how to demangle this stuff in the future, the pattern is fairly simple: each letter relates to a basic type or modifier. The modifiers are first. H is assoc array. Then is the key: A is array, y is immutable, a is char. So Aya == array of immutable chars, aka immutable(char)[], aka string. Then the value for aa: yAa: immutable Array of char, aka immutable(char[]). If you need to look up the meanings of the letters, it is on the dlang.org abi page.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe So `HAyayAa` means `immutable(char)[immutable(char[])]`?

Comment: Almost, but not quite: it is `immutable(char[])[immutable(char)[]]`. You missed one of the 'A's, which means Array of, and I think you read the value before the key. Key then value mangled. A simpler example would be Hai. H means assoc array, the next two types are key then value, a means char, i means int. So `Hai` == `int[char]`. And then, when reading the modifier chars, if you see one, it applies to all the rest until a basic type. So Aya, 'a' is the basic type so that's where it ends. Then reading the rest: Array of immutable char: immutable(char)[]. yAa immutables the whole array too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this code to your file with main():

```
void aaHack() {
    import std.stdio;
    writeln(typeid(immutable(char[])[string]));
}
```

and recompile, see if it works. I'm sure your error is caused by an old bug in associative arrays that is incredibly hard to reproduce; it seems to come and go at random, making it hard to fix too. The exact type needed is something I'm not sure about, I'm guessing there based on an eyeball demangle, but I think this is it.

Anyway, the associative array implementation in D right now is stuck in a halfway point between two ideas: implemented in the language via special runtime calls, and implemented in the library with no compiler support except syntax sugar. Again, I'm not *sure* this is the cause, but it came in around these changes were made, so I think that's it. What I believe is happening is you reference the AA type, which then gets used via the half-done library type, but then the functions need the typeinfo for the compiler's magic calls, and it never gets correctly inserted. Or something.

But the hack workaround is to forcibly mention the typeid manually somewhere to bridge the gap. My cgi.d has a block of 14 lines of working around this thing over and over again: fully immutable keys and/or values seem to be the edge case that breaks it, whereas tail-immutable arrays (e.g. strings) work fine. Maybe the compiler assumes the other thing will be stripped off and isn't, idk, but the hack has worked reasonably well for me.

Comment: I'm not actually using any weird associative arrays, just `immutable string[string]` but it still worked. Thanks!